# Pass and Get Id to Ajax with datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

Loan account number is a unique number that I want to get and pass to query the database. As of now, With the code below, I could select each column **but** couldn't select number longer than five.

So since that didn't work, I am trying to see if I can pass Id so as to select the account no and pass it to the controller.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dailyload').DataTable({
            pageLength: 10,
            ajax: {
                url: '/DailyInterest/Details',
                dataSrc: ''
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    title: "Loan Account No",
                    data: 'loanAccountNo'

                },
                {
                    title: "Loan Amount Written off",
                    data: 'amountWrittenOff'
                }

            ]
        });

var table = $('.dataTable').on('click', 'tbody td', function() {

  //get textContent of the TD
    console.log('TD cell textContent : ', this.textContent)

   $.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    url: "/DailyInterest/GetInterestCalculated/" + this.textContent,
    contentType: "application/json",
       success: function (result) {
           console.log("this is the result: ",result )

    }
})

}).data());
})

    })
``
```

Comment: What you mean by "_couldn't select number longer than five_" Please share few examples to clarify.

Comment: I tried debugging with a figure less than 6 and I was able to get the number in my controller.

Comment: @where the error is coming from. The number is too long for an int data type. The digit is 11. I am able to get the number now in the asp.net mvc controller. ```Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Int64'.``` Which is raising another error. That is beyond the scope of this question